# What does the "@" symbol in the Running Applications/Services mean?

Tags: applications, services

What does the "@" symbol in front of the time given in the right column of *Running Applications/Services* mean?

See screenshot below.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9505)
OS: 4.2.2

[image: Running services]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: What phone and Android version is this on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9505), 4.2.2

Comment: We have the same phone and Android version, but I haven't seen those symbols on my phone. Hmmm.

Comment: All my Nexus 4.3 devices don't show this either. Seems like it's Sammy specific (maybe even for some sub models only)

Comment: My 4.2 Nexus 10 gives an `=` sign on Google Services, but no `@` signs.

Comment: I've looked in the source for this settings page in AOSP, but can't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the process has been running longer than 99 hours, 99 minutes, and 99 seconds. It's a formatting bug.

The second hour digit, after reaching '9', will simply continue with the next characted from the ascii alphabet:

```
0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Where in this case ':' means 10, ';' means 11, '<' means 12, etc.

For example, '<5:12:34' means 125:12:34 and '?5:12:34' means 155:12:34.

It's fixed in Android 4.3

The Related bug report is here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41401

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Samsung Galaxy S4 but based on the information provided it seems like this is the time frame since the services has been active (i.e. Service "com.sec.phone" *started about* 1:46:26 ago).
I can see that this is the case because a few other services have the same start time, at which point you either turn your phone ON (and Android initiated those services automatically).